# How to Automatically Move Files to Folders in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, file-management

I have 1 Folder that contain 500 file txt and 50 empty Folders that sorted by name (Folder 1, Folder 2, etc).

How to automatically move per 10 file to folders that I create?

So in the end 50 folders will contain 10 file each.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, there is no automation in Windows to do what you want.

Comment: If its a once only task, do it by hand with a file/folder comparison tool, it will be faster than writing scripts etc.

Comment: And what have you done to achieve this? This is not a free scripting site. It is a site that helps people who have helped themselves. So this site can help you with your code if you have any issues with your code. Feel free to share your code and we can help you debug your code. But we cannot code anything for you from scratch.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a code writing service. What have you tried? What tools and knowledge do you have available? Also, the question is unclear: which ten files, when?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a some ways to automatically move files from one folder to another on your Windows 10/11 PC. One of them is to launch a batch script that can move files based on their age or name. Another one is to use a tool like DropIt, QuickMove, or Files 2 Folder that can move files based on rules or filters.

Here is a link for DropIt:
http://www.dropitproject.com/

I hope that this will be a good alternative for your challengingly task
If you need more assistance from me, feel free to ask away!!

Answer (score 0):

The way to automate tasks in Windows 10 is with Windows PowerShell. Here's one way:

```
$Source = 'c:\Path\to\folder\with\500files'
$Dest   = 'c:\Path\to\folder\with\Folders(1-50)'

ForEach($folder in (Get-ChildItem $Dest -Directory | sort {[Int]($_.Name -replace '\D')}).FullName ) {
    Get-ChildItem $Source -File | Select -First 10 | Move-Item -Destination $folder
}
```

- The [ForEach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-7.4) statement executes a statement block for each item in a collection.
- [Get-ChildItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.4) retrievce the contents of a folder with the `-Directory` parameter limiting returned items to directories only.
- `sort {[Int]($_.Name -replace '\D')}` orders the folders based on the value of the numeric portions of their names:

  | gci $dest -name | gci $dest -name | sort {[Int]($_ -replace '\D')} |
  | --- | --- |
  | Folder1 | Folder1 |
  | Folder10 | Folder2 |
  | Folder11 | Folder3 |
  | ... | Folder4 |
  | Folder19 | Folder5 |
  | Folder2 | Folder6 |
  | Folder20 | Folder7 |
  | ... | Folder8 |
  | Folder49 | Folder9 |
  | Folder5 | Folder10 |
  | Folder50 | ... |
  | Folder6 | Folder47 |
  | Folder7 | Folder48 |
  | Folder8 | Folder49 |
  | Folder9 | Folder50 |